# Get face rotation Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am getting the intersections of mouse click with Three.js like this

```
me.vector.set(
    (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1,
    -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1,
    0.5);
me.vector.unproject(app.camera);
me.ray.set(app.camera.position, me.vector.sub(app.camera.position).normalize());
var intersects = me.ray.intersectObjects(app.colliders, false);
```

So, i got intersects perfectly, with following properties:

`distance, face, faceIndex, object, point`, and then I execute a function.

The problem is the following:

I want to detect when i click a face of a cube, that is like a floor, in the next example would be the gray face.

sorry about my engilsh D:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebGL defines vertices and faces with coordinates, colors, and **normals**. A face normal is a normalized vector, perpendicular to the face plane (and generally pointing 'outside' the mesh). It defines its orientation and enables calculation of lightning for instance. In three.js you can access it via `face.normal`.

- If your floor-like faces are stricly horizontal, then their normals are all precisely `{x:0,y:1,z:0}`. And since normals are normalized, simply check whether `face.normal.y === 1` also checks that x and y equal 0.
- If your faces are not strictly horizontal, you may need to set a limit angle with the y-axis. You can calculate this angle with `var angle=Math.acos(Yaxis.dot(faceNormal))` where `Yaxis=new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0)`.